# CORS issue in a Heroku deployed MERN Application

Tags: reactjs, heroku, deployment, cors, mern

I have developed a MERN application. While working locally everything was running smoothly but once I deployed it on Heroku, it started giving me CORS error.
I faced the same issue during local deployment as well, so I resolved it using 'cors' npm package and everything was working.

The error displayed in the browser debug console is:

> Access to fetch at 'https://expense-manager-b.herokuapp.com/auth/signup' from origin 'https://expense-manager-f.herokuapp.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

The code snipped in my index.js file in the backend is:

```
import express from "express";
import cors from 'cors';
import { connectToMongoose } from './db.js';
import * as authRoutes from './routes/auth.js';
import * as transactionRoutes from './routes/transaction.js'

const app = express()
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());
connectToMongoose();

const port = process.env.PORT || 5000

app.use('/auth',authRoutes.router);
app.use('/transaction',transactionRoutes.router);

app.listen( port, () => {
  console.log(`Expense Tracker listening at http://localhost:${port}`)
})
```

My Heroku Logs are:

> 2022-01-06T08:03:10.065650+00:00 app[web.1]: >
> expense-tracker-backend@1.0.0 start /app
> 2022-01-06T08:03:10.065651+00:00 app[web.1]: > node index.js
> 2022-01-06T08:03:10.065651+00:00 app[web.1]:
> 2022-01-06T08:03:13.340656+00:00 app[web.1]: Connected to MongoDB
> 2022-01-06T08:03:13.346735+00:00 app[web.1]: Expense Tracker listening
> at http://localhost:27038 2022-01-06T08:03:13.738063+00:00
> heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
> 2022-01-06T08:03:16.161549+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info
> method=OPTIONS path="/auth/signup"
> host=expense-manager-b.herokuapp.com
> request_id=42b9f065-a9d0-4dd9-b867-740314dfe850 fwd="103.199.173.140"
> dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=24ms status=204 bytes=301
> protocol=https 2022-01-06T08:03:16.432708+00:00 app[web.1]: Before
> Find 2022-01-06T08:03:46.384475+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error
> code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=POST path="/auth/signup"
> host=expense-manager-b.herokuapp.com
> request_id=8d652b82-cd0f-425c-ba04-851d37bef001 fwd="103.199.173.140"
> dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=30000ms status=503 bytes=0
> protocol=https

While searching for answer, I found that I should also specify from which origin should the request be allowed, hence I also include origin parameter as below in my index.js file.

```
app.use(cors({origin:'*'}))
```

But is doesn't resolve anything.

Using Heroku Logs, I found that you need to allow access to database from every IP, hence I also modified IP list to 0.0.0.0/0, still the issue was not resolved.

This is my first time asking the question, I hope I have provided with everything that you might need to help me resolve it.

Edited:
I am sending request to API for several operations. Below mentioned code is responsible for sending request to API for login scenario.

```
const onSubmit = async (e)=>{
        e.preventDefault();

        try{
            const response = await fetch('https://expense-manager-b.herokuapp.com/auth/login',

                {
                    method:"POST",
                    headers:{
                        'Content-type':'application/json',
                        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
                    },
                    body: JSON.stringify({
                        email: login.email,
                        password: login.password
                    })
                }
            );

            const json = await response.json();

            if(json.status === 'success'){
                localStorage.setItem('authToken',json.authToken);
                console.log(localStorage.getItem('authToken'));
                navigate('https://expense-manager-f.herokuapp.com/dashboard');
            }
            else{
                //TODO: Add alert box here to display that Credentials are wrong.
                
            }
        }
        catch(error){
            console.log(error);
        }
    }
```

Comment: make sure that your app are listening to port 80. you can test it with hardcoding port to 80, after that check your api with postman

Comment: Show the frontend code that is responsible for sending the request in question.

Comment: @jub0bs Hi, I have added the frontend code(function, sending request to API). Hope it gives you more idea about the problem.

Comment: @AbhishekHolani See http://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html. At the very least, you need to configure your backend to allow the origin of your frontend and the `Content-Type` request header.